# Ordering records that are timestamped

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have a tricky one here.

I have a number of results in a table, this table has id, market, date and points.

I want to get all the records for a given month and then output all the points for each day, in order.

I'm not sure of the best way to do this? Her are my options, well my ideas, I could set a loop that will execute for every day of the given month, this will run a query to find every record for that day and will do this for every day of the month, this will then be easy to order a format the records but i'm thinking its not a good idea to query the database that many times.

The second idea i to query the database for all the records for that date, order them by the date. However i can see come problems here when outputting the information for each day, well it will be a long job then the first i think.

Any ideas? anyone done something like this before and could lend a helping hand? Any advise would be more than welcome!

Thanks.

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($getresults))
{
    $day = FALSE;

    foreach ($row as $row)
    {
        $day_res = date("Y-m-d H:m:s", strtotime($row["date"]));

        if (!$day || $day != $day_res)
        {
            $day = $day_res;
            echo '<h1>'.$day.'</h1>';
        }

        echo $row['date'] . " " . $row["id"] . ": " . $row["market"] . 
                    "/" . $row["points"] . "<br/>";
    }
 }
```

This is the output i get from it:

```
1970-01-01 00:01:00

3 3: 3/3
3 3: 3/3
2012-01-13 09:01:06

E E: E/E
E E: E/E
1970-01-01 00:01:00

2 2: 2/2
2 2: 2/2
- -: -/-
- -: -/-
1970-01-01 00:01:00

4 4: 4/4
4 4: 4/4
```

and that more or less repeats for a while.

Thanks again.

Comment: How is "date" formatted? Unix-Timestamp or something like 2012-01-13?

Comment: check my answer again ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

at first the query to get all for a given month ordered by date:

```
SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `date` LIKE '2012-01%' ORDER BY date;
```

here the php loop to show it:

```
$day = FALSE;
foreach ($results as $result){
    $day_res = date("d", strtotime($result["date"]));
    if (!$day || $day != $day_res){
        $day = $day_res;
        echo '<h1>'.$day.'</h1>';
    }
    echo $result["id"].": ".$result["market"]."/".$result["points"]."<br/>";
}
```

Ok here for your structure:

```
$day = FALSE;
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($getresults))
{
        $day_res = date("Y-m-d H:m:s", strtotime($row["date"]));

        if (!$day || $day != $day_res)
        {
            $day = $day_res;
            echo '<h1>'.$day.'</h1>';
        }

        echo $row['date'] . " " . $row["id"] . ": " . $row["market"] . 
                    "/" . $row["points"] . "<br/>";
 }
```

Comment: There is no summing of the points in your code. I think you should add that to the query as I stated in my answer. Makes things less complex.

Comment: he dont want it to sum up, only to display it. or have i missed it in the question?

Comment: sure... i put out the day, then all markets for it, then the next day and so on...

Comment: No i didn't ask for the sum, but i can sure use it so thanks @stefandoorn

Comment: `date LIKE '2012-01%'` will probably do a conversion to `Char` and not be able to use any index on `date`.

Comment: The php you gave me is working... A bit.... For some reason, some of my dates are coming up as 1970 and some of the output like date and points are coming up as 'E'?

Comment: That didn't do anything. Also i've noticed that ever time i refresh some of the times increase...? :\ But only the seconds....

Comment: mhhh, add a print_r($row) on the top of the while. whats the output for the rows?

Answer (score 3):

If that date is only a date, then you could try something like this:

```
SELECT t.date, SUM(t.points) FROM table t WHERE date BETWEEN [STARTDATE HERE] AND [ENDDATE HERE] GROUP BY t.date
```

What it does? It selects everything the date & the sum of the points of that day, because we group all the results based on a day. So for every unique date in your table you will get a row with a result. Use the WHERE date statement to define from which month you need the selection.

Addition: the thing shown is only valid if date is in format like: YYYY-MM-DD. In case you have a timestamp (YYYY-MM-DD HH:ii:ss) you could try to change the query to:

```
SELECT t.date, SUM(t.points) FROM table t WHERE date BETWEEN [STARTDATE HERE] AND [ENDDATE HERE] GROUP BY DAYOFMONTH(t.date)
```

This ensures that you will group them by the day of the month (1 to 31) based on the dates from your table.

Comment: If `\`date\`` is `datetime` or `timestamp` you can use `WHERE \`date\` >= [STARTDATE HERE] AND \`date\` < [STARTDATE HERE] + INTERVAL 1 MONTH`

Comment: I used some of your code with mine: $getresults = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM results WHERE date BETWEEN '2012-$monthid-01 00:00:00' AND '2012-$monthid-31 23:59:59' GROUP BY DAYOFMONTH(date)"); It runs but in a strange way, it outputs two records then loads for 60 seconds and i get this error: Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 60 seconds exceeded in members/pages/results2.php on line 167 when on this bit of code: while($row = mysql_fetch_array($getresults)) can you see what im doing wrong?

Comment: If you want me to put this in the original post to make it easier on the eyes just say.

Comment: Try your queries also with phpMyAdmin to ensure they are valid. And then, it could be that they take so long that PHP times out. It could be necessary to add indexes to the table in order to speed up search. The MySQL manual will help you with that, but for this one it could be:

ALTER TABLE results ADD INDEX search (date)